# How to create a new array of even numbers from an existing array?

Tags: swift

I am trying to create a function that takes an array of Int, and returns a new array of all of the even numbers in the original array.

I have been fumbling around with this code (I am a very new beginner)

```
let numberArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] 
var newArray: [Int] = []

func newInt(newEven: Int, newArray: [Int]) -> Int {   
        for newEven in numberArray{
        var index = 0
        index += 1
        if newEven % 2 == 0 {
        newArray.insert(newEven, at:[index])
    }
    return newEven   
    } 
}

print(newArray)
```

Comment: When posting code with a question, you can highlight your code and use `command + k` to properly format it. The quotation formatting you used in your original post would be appropriate for highlighting an error you get in the compiler or for quoting documentation. Alternatively, [Visual Studios Code](https://code.visualstudio.com) is a great text editor that you can utilize, as well. You can use `command + ]` in VS Code will indent your text and StackOverflow will format the indented portion as code, too.

Comment: May be something like `func getMultiples(of number: Int, source: [Int], output: inout [Int]) { for element in source where element.isMultiple(of: number) { output.append(element) } }` `getMultiples(of: 2, source: numberArray, output: &newArray)`

Comment: @LeoDabus Don't just give away the answer. This is a homework problem

Comment: @Alexander at least OP tried something

Comment: @LeoDabus Yes, so build on top of that, rather than giving it away.

Comment: Feel free to compose an answer covering all issues

Answer (score 3):

This is a good start! Here are some pointers:

### 1. Formatting

The formatting needs some work. Generally, every new scope (`{ ... }`) should introduce a new layer of indentation, like so:

```
let numberArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] 
var newArray: [Int] = []

func newInt(newEven: Int, newArray: [Int]) -> Int {   
    for newEven in numberArray{
        var index = 0
        index += 1
        if newEven % 2 == 0 {
            newArray.insert(newEven, at:[index])
        }
        return newEven   
    } 
}

print(newArray)
```

Now we can make some observations:
 1. `index` is scoped to the `for` loop body, and will always have the same value of `0`, and then `1` after the next line.
 2. The return statement is within the `for` loop body, and unconditional. This function will always return the value of the first element of `numberArray`
 3. The return type of this function is `Int`. But in your question, you state that you want this to return an array of all of the even numbers. So your return type will have to be `Array<Int>` (a.k.a. `[Int]`), not just `Int`.

### 2. Compilation issues

This function has several errors that will prevent compilation:

1. The return statement is within a loop body. If `numberArray` is empty, and the `for` loop body is never entered, then you don't hit the `return` statement. Once control reaches the end of the function, what value should be returned? It's not defined, so that's an error. In Swift, all code paths through a function must return a value. (with the exception of Void functions, which implicitly return nothing at the end)
2. You're trying to call `Array.insert(_:at:)` with a second argument of `[index]`, which is an array literal of type `Array<Int>`. It should just be `index`.

### 3. Logical issues

1. Your function introduces a parameter called `newArray`, which shadows the global variable `newArray` on the line before it. The global variable isn't necessary, and you should delete it.
2. Your function operates over `numberArray`, but doesn't explicitly take it as input via a parameter. Rather than hardcoding a reference to a global variable like `numberArray`, you should use a parameter.
3. The parameter `newEven` is unused, and is shadowed by the local variable of the `for` loop
4. Your function name `newInt(newEven:newArray:)` doesn't describe what the function does. Consider a function signature  like `func allEvens(in input: [Int]) -> [Int]`
5. You never actually call this function. You declare it, but never told the program to run it.
6. You don't need to use `Array.insert(_:at:)`. You can simply use `Array.append`, which will automatically append elements to the end of the array.

## 4. Recommendations

1. Fix the method signature. You want the function to take some numbers, and output only the even numbers. Model that in code: `func allEvens(in input: [Int]) -> [Int]`
2. Create a new empty array locally (within the function), into which the even numbers will be stored. As you loop over the `input` array, check every number if it's even, and if so, append it to the `evens` array.
3. Return the `evens` array.

Answer (score 0):

```
let numberArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] 

var newArray = numberArray.filter({$0 % 2 == 0})
```

This should return a new array with even numbers.

Comment: or `filter { $0.isMultiple(of: 2) }`

Comment: For this assignment I am asked to use a function and a loop to accomplish that. I think I have the right pieces up there I just can't make It coherent. They want an answer with newArray in it

Comment: There is no reason to downvote, as the answer is correct I had given.. the same as Leos answer.

Answer (score 0):

As [LeoDabus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2303865/leo-dabus) mentioned in his comment, the functionality you're seeking is already contained within Swift's Standard Library, so it's not really necessary to write a dedicated function to accomplish that task. Here's how you would do it:

```
let numberArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
let newArray = numberArray.filter { $0.isMultiple(of: 2) }

print(newArray) // [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

In this, you're using the `filter` whether `$0` (where `$0` is an element in your array) is a multiple of the number you specified in the parameter, in this case, 2.

As you see [in the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/binaryinteger/3126998-ismultiple#), `isMultiple(of:)` returns a `Bool` (`true` or `false`). This is the signature:

```
func isMultiple(of other: Self) -> Bool
```

I would recommend having a peek at [this post](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/swift-guide-to-map-filter-reduce/) covering the topics of `map`, `filter`, and `reduce`. These are useful things to know when starting out in Swift.

Additionally, I've found [Dash](https://kapeli.com/dash) to be extremely helpful in navigating documetation for Swift.

## Update

I should have read your question more thoroughly, as I missed the part where you've gotta do it with a loop. Swift has a cool method called `forEach`, which I'm a huge fan of. Using that methodology, it would look something like this:

```
func filter(array: [Int], forMultiplesOf multiple: Int) -> [Int] {

    // Create a landing spot for whatever is a multiple...it starts as empty
    var newArray: [Int] = []

    // This is not the most compact way, but it satisfies the loop constraint
    array.forEach { number in
        if number % multiple == 0 {
            newArray.append(number)
        }
    }

    // Once you're done with the loop, then return the new array you declared at the beginning
    return newArray
}
```

And you'd call it like so:

```
let newArrayUsingFunction = filter(array: numberArray, forMultiplesOf: 2)
```

What you're doing here is passing in 2 parameters to the function (array & multiple) to return an array of Ints. See comments in code for what's going on

Comment: He stated that this is for a homework assignment, and he explicitly has to use a `loop`. He's essentially being taught how `filter` and friends are implemented.

Comment: Oops :) I should have read more thoroughly. I saw it and thought, "I was once in his shoes" and went for the most concise way.

Comment: @Adrain No problem :) In cases like these, I try to both fix their code as-is, and suggest the better alternative. Side-stepping the problem by using something like `filter` doesn't help them learn how to implement code like this